# How do I remove characters between 2 delimiters?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a string from which I need to remove digits between the first hyphen and the underscore.

Strings are:

```
string ProjectName1 = "1234-5678_abcd-efgh-(5000)|type";
string ProjectName2 = "0-4378_abcd-efgh-(5000)|type";
```

I have tried

```
Regex x = new Regex("(\\-\\)(.*?)(\\_\\)");
string repl = "";
string removeDigits = x.Replace(ProjectName, "$1" + repl + "$3");
```

Result should be

```
ProjectName1="1234-abcd-efgh-(5000)|type";
ProjectName2="0-abcd-efgh-(5000)|type";
```

I have tried the above code but get the following error.

```
Error message: parsing "(\-\)(.*?)(\_\)" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.
```

I have tried different things with regex but always get an error similar to that.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=^.*?)-\d+_", "-")` will replace ***only*** the first occurrence of digits surrounded by `"-"` and `"_"` with `"-"`

Comment: ...whereas `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=^[^-]*)-\d+_", "-")` will replace digits surrounded by `"-"` and `"_"` with `"-"` ***only*** if they occur at the first `"-"` in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex seems to do the trick:

```
Regex x = new Regex("^(\\d+-).*?_(.*)$");
```

Results from both sample inputs are

```
x.Replace(ProjectName1, "$1$2"); //1234-abcd-efgh-(5000)|type
x.Replace(ProjectName2, "$1$2"); //0-abcd-efgh-(5000)|type
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to go that far by using capture group if the input is very predictable

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"-\d+_");
string result = regex.Replace(ProjectName1, "-", 1);
```

you know that you want to remove the digit + the underscore while keeping the dash. so you can simply just remove the whole thing and add the dash in again. By restricting it to replace only one instance you will be only replacing the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you need - do you need to replace all digits followed by an underscore?

Try this:

```
string formatted1 = Regex.Replace(ProjectName1, @"\d+_", string.Empty);
```

Comment: No, just the digits between the first dash and the underscore